# How do I delete a specific data if I have the id rather than the whole collection in react using fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
const myFetchedNotes = [];

const url = "https://firebaseurl/notes.json";

async function deleteNote(id) {
// const request = new Request(
//    `https://firebaseurl/notes.json`,
//    {
//       method: 'DELETE'
//    }
// );

```
  // const response = await fetch(request);
  // return await response.json()

  const response = await fetch(
     url + '/' + { id } + '.json', {
     method: "delete"
  });
  
  return await response.json();
```

}

Comment: Even if I don't add the .json in response and change it to this code
      const request = new Request(
         `https://firbaseurl/notes.json/${id}`,
         {
            method: 'DELETE'
         }
      );

I get a Access to fetch at *** from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Comment: can someone help me with this... If I uncomment the code,, comment the below code and run it... i.e if I run const request = new Request( https://firebaseurl/notes.json, { method: 'DELETE' } ); const response = await fetch(request); return await response.json() I am losing the whole collection in the database but if I use the below code to delete only a particular key with the id then it is giving me a bad request